# Mongodb count not calling callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have following code in my nodejs app:

```
db.open(function(err, db) {
     while (item = stream.read())
     {
        var parsedDate = parseDateFromString(item.title);
        var movieName = parseNameFromString(item.title);
        var channelName = parseChannelFromString(item.title);

        //var doc = { "name": movieName, "channel": channelName, "showed": parsedDate, "showDate": parsedDate.format(), "run_id": new Date().toString()};
        var doc = { "name": movieName, "channel": channelName, "showed": parsedDate, "run_id": new Date().toString()};

        db.collection('programs', function(err, collection) {
           collection.find({'name' : doc.name, "channel" : doc.channel}).count(function(countErr, count) {
             console.log('count!');
              if(count == 0)
                 insertDocument(collection, doc);
              else
                console.log('Found match from db with name ' + matchDoc.name);
            });
         });

      } // End of while
  }); // End of Open
```

Problem is that count! is never reported. So collection.count is not calling its callback. I checked that collection.find is called multiple times. What could cause that problem?

Comment: Try to console the `err` in collection.

Comment: I don't fine any thing wrong here unless you don't get `collection` or `doc` object is undefined.

Comment: If i change coll.count to coll.find it works properly, strange things :).

Comment: my insert inside find is doing same thing. Not calling callback :(. I see "inserting..." texts, but not a record added:

function insertDocument(programsCollection, prog) {
   console.log('inserting...');
   programsCollection.insert(prog, function(err, records) {
      console.log("Record added");
   });
}

Comment: Ok, just a throw in, in the manual I do not see a callback specified for `count()` http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/...? (And `insert()` http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/ ?)

Comment: They are built into nodejs mongodb driver:
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#insert

Comment: Ah, cool, thanks ;) Looking into it, nothing pops up with MONGO CALLBACK on google : o

Comment: Ok, I found something here http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html you have ... ok, you will make it? ;) Give me a holler please if it works!

Comment: Yeah it would be lot easier if I had a error.

Comment: No, I meant "options is an object of parameters, if you use a callback, set `safe` to `true`...

Comment: From the source https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1.4/lib/mongodb/collection/core.js#L18 you *MUST* supply a `docs`.